# Replacement for node-fibers in Node 16

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fibers, node-fibers

I am using node-fibers for webpack.config.js and I want to upgrade my Node version.
Is there any replacement package that does what fibers does?
Is my only option to refactor code at the moment?

webpack.config.js:

```
loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap : true,
        implementation: require('sass-embedded'),
        sassOptions: {
          fiber: require('fibers'),
```

Comment: No, Node.js 16 or later is declared to be unsupported in the documentation: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/. I recommend reverting to using the default sass.

Comment: Could you clarify on reverting to default sass

Comment: Remove your custom configuration for `fiber` and `implementation`, and install the https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass package which is used by default.